# Can I use "countIFS" with a filter?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PlPmShZ4SnkxAqBTg5xY_LHaNokGaFli4Wc7MjV_Jqo/edit?usp=sharing

I want to count how many `paid` is for city `MB` and then how many `paid` is for city `UB`.

I tried to use COUNTIFS and `=COUNTA((QUERY(C4:C42, "select D where D='paid' and C='MB'", 0)))` but I cannot make it work.

Somebody got an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already tried the query solution, please use these two formulas:

**in cell `B2`**:

```
=query(D6:E10, "select count(D) where D='paid' and E='MB' label count(D) ''")
```

**in cell `D2`**:

```
=query(D6:E10, "select count(D) where D='paid' and E='UB' label count(D) ''")
```

You can read more about how the QUERY function works in the [help center](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343).

***Note***: In the end of the formula we use `label count(D) ''`. That translates to "take the label of the results in column D and replace it with nothing. Try omitting that part of the formula and see what happens ".

Comment: works perfectly. Thank you..... Would you know how to get rid of `#N/A` if there is no data, no match?

Comment: I don't see why it would give you `#N/A`. If there is no data/match the query would have a red line under it saying _"Query completed with an empty output"_. You must be referring to a different formula. Please share a link and maybe start another question. In any case the usual way is to use IFERROR.

Comment: this is exactly what I want `=IFERROR(query(D5:EG113, "select count(E) where E='UB' label count(E) ''"),"")`